# Getting Values from DataGridView into 2D array

Tags: c++, for-loop, access-violation, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I want to get all values from from datagridview and set 2D double array.I have tried alot of syntax but it not works. Here is the code and it gives *access violation exception* during converting .

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    int **KillRatetemp;
    double **Costtemp;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KillRatetemp=new int*[26];
        Costtemp=new double*[26];

        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            KillRatetemp[i]=new int[9];
            Costtemp[i]=new double[9];
        }
      }



    void SetValues()
            {
     dataGridView1->Rows->Add(27);
     dataGridView2->Rows->Add(27);




         for(int i=0;i<=26;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
             {
                 dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value="1";
                 dataGridView2->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value="1";
             }
         }
```

//It works with i<26,j<9

```
    for(int i=0;i<=26;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
        {

          Costtemp[i][j]= System::Convert::ToDouble(dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value);
          KillRatetemp[i][j]= System::Convert::ToDouble(dataGridView2->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value);
           }
       }


 };
```

Afterwards i want to place the 2D array again in Datagridview.
I am using  Visual Studio 2010 Windows Form Application,Pure MSIL common Language Runtime Support.
Kindly solve my problem .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Int type to Double type conversion

Comment: No its not the matter